# An error occurred during comment submission while on audit posts

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, review-audits, error-message

There is a red error showing on audit posts when reviewer wants to post a comment. I think this is something that should be fixed, as it's confusing behaviour.

See the demonstration below:

[image]

I believe this start happening after the change, that [commenting should not lead to failing review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306916/55075). However is the red error is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Would have been helpful to check the console for the actual error.  If you can repro and post this info in an [edit], it would be nice.  I'd wager you couldn't comment on it because it was gone.  Poof.  Somebody hit it with the spamaway while you were racing to add a comment.  You can't comment on something that doesn't exist :/

Comment: @Won't I'll check for the exact error on the next audit. This one is quiet obvious, but there are some posts which aren't obvious and you want to inform users about the problem with their post and still select to close it, so they're aware and have possibility for further improvements, even they post has been removed and got into audit (without any comments, it's not clear for new users what went wrong). So I think it should show some more user-friendly message like: 'The commenting on this post has been disabled/locked.'